# How to prevent python urllib3 from caching response

Tags: python, caching, http-headers, debian

I am polling the same url several times in a row with urllib3.  I have profiled the requests and I am getting the header:

Cache-Control: no-transform, max-age=120

On requests after the first I am getting the cached version of the page rather than the request being run again.  I have no control over the headers returned from the server, how can I prevent the caching?

I am on Debian Squeeze and this is running python 2.6.6

```
pool = urllib3.HTTPConnectionPool('itunes.apple.com')
request = pool.request('GET', '/webObjects/MZStore.woa/wa/viewTop?
                       selected_tab_index=0&startIndex=0&genreId=36', 
                       headers = {'Host': 'itunes.apple.com', 
                       'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate', 'X-Apple-Tz': -18000, 
                       'X-Apple-Store-Front': '143441-1,2')
```

Comment: Please show the call to urllib3 with parameters.

Answer (score 3):

urllib3 has no native caching built in. Are you sure it's not the server responding with cached results?

Comment: That is very possible.  Is there any way to avoid getting the cached response back from the server aside from waiting?

Comment: That really depends on the server and the logic it implements. As James mentioned below, you could try sending a cache-control:no-cache header. You could also try appending some query param to the URL like a timestamp.

Answer (score 2):

Try adding the following headers:

Cache-Control: no-cache

Pragma: no-cache

Expires: Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT

Comment: I came here because when I ran a script to check my server was running, I got a cached result.  Adding these headers worked for me; thanks!  Note I'm using Python Requests